# how to get the url of the view calling the decorator in the decorator?

Tags: python, django, django-views

In a django app I have a decorator called `my_dec` , I want to use the url of the view that is calling the decorator in the decorator, for example if the code of view is like this :

```
@my_dec(key)
def my_view
   pass
```

I want something like this :

```
def my_dec(key)
   print #url of "my_view"
```

how can I access the `url of my_view` or any other view that is calling the decorator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using function based views.
In your decorator you can access the request object of your function view.
Here's an example code

```
def my_dec(func):
    def wrapped(request):
        print request.path_info
        return func(request)
    return wrapped
```

And then you can use this decorator on a view like this:

```
@my_dec
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse(...)
```

This example simply prints out the url associated with your view.
Note that in your view you have access to the entire request object and can fish out any information you want.

This example works on function based views but can easily be modified to work on class-based views as well